# Web.GetFileByServerRelativeUrl throws "Value does not fall within expected range"

Tags: c#, sharepoint, sharepoint-clientobject, sharepoint-online

I have a SP Online site where I store Documents, I have no issues adding/retrieving documents but in the delete flow I get an error during retrieval of a `File` object.

```
public static void DeleteDocument()
{
    using (ClientContext ctx = ClientContextFactory.Create("https://my-sponline-site.sharepoint.com/sites/documentsite"))
    {
        Web web = ctx.Web;
        ctx.Load(web);
        ctx.ExecuteQuery();

        string relativeUrl = "/Documents/images.jpg";

        File file = web.GetFileByServerRelativeUrl(relativeUrl);
        ctx.Load(file);
        file.DeleteObject();

        ctx.ExecuteQuery();
    }
}
```

Full Url of the file is "https://my-sponline-site.sharepoint.com/sites/documentsite/Documents/images.jpg" (No more accessible 2016-12-07)

When I execute this, I get a `ServerException` :

> Value does not fall within the expected range.

The Context is working fine as I'm able to add/retrieve items from the library and the context user is *administrator*.

I tried adding the web url to the relativeUrl so it would be "/documentsite/Documents/images.jpg" but I get the same error.

I can't seem to figure this out, any suggestions?

Thanks

Comment: since its serverrelative - you should add /sites/documentsite

Comment: Seems worth noting that although the file-retrieval wants a server-relative URL, it appears that you still need to use a context created with the URL of the correct site (or else you get the same "Value does not fall within the expected range" error).

Answer (score 28):

```
string relativeUrl = "/sites/documentsite/Documents/images.jpg";
```